# Move to next flagged message in Mutt

Tags: mutt

Is it possible to move to the next flagged message in Mutt?  In looking at the [development manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/devel/manual.html), I wasn't able to see anything that would let me do this.  I'm looking for something like `<next-new>`, but for skipping around to the next flagged message.  If there's nothing like this in Mutt, can I fake it with macros?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just search for the next flagged message: `/` followed by `~F`. Well, the only drawback is that this doesn't work from the pager menu (but this would be a valid RFE).

And you can write a macro with the value: `<search>~F\r`

Note: similarly, I suppose that `<next-new>` is almost the same as `<search>~N\r` in the index menu (the only difference I can see is the different error message when there are no new messages).

Note 2: from the pager, I suppose that a macro `<exit><search>~F\r<display-message>` would do what you want.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I knew I was missing something.  I didn't think about using a pattern in a search like that.

Comment: See also `l` (and then enter `~F`) to limit the view to only the flagged messages.

Comment: And RTFM: Have a look at `man muttrc`. Try `man -Pless\ +/flagged muttrc` or `man -Pcol\ -b muttrc | sed '/^[A-Z ] \{0,5\}[^ ]/H;/flagged/{x;p;x;q;};d'`

Answer (score 3):

## Bind *important messages* to `I` keypress in `.muttrc`

In addition to [vinc17's correct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150431/27653) answer, I would present two lines I've added into my `.muttrc`

```
# Bind to I key in index view:
macro index I  "<search>~F\n"                     "Search for next important"
# Bint to I key in pager:
macro pager I  "<exit><search>~F\n<display-message>" "Jump to next important"
```

Nota: I've choosed `I` after reading help in both mode and ensuring previous use of `I` (uppercase) will prompt `Key is not bound.  Press '?' for help.` in both context.

Answer (score 0):

To do the same for tagged messages, just use `~T` instead of `~F`.

[See also this.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503645/259089)