# Move to next tagged message in mutt

Tags: mutt

I tagged a bunch of messages in mutt index.

How can one jump to the next tagged message in mutt? Is it possible to just show all tagged messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Search next tagged message: `/` then **`~T`**. Show tagged messages only:`l` then **`~T`**.

---

*Now, there's an exhaustive answer:*

You **T**agged a set of messages. Now, you want to go to/select the next **T**agged message:

Use `/` then **`~T`** and you're all set.

In case you temporarily want to be presented with only your Tagged messages press `l` (limit results) then **`~T`**. To revert and show all messages again, limit `l` to `all`.

See also [(neo)mutt pattern modifiers](https://neomutt.org/guide/advancedusage#tab-patterns) for more info on how to modify your "Searching, Limiting and Tagging" operations.

Goody ahead: mutt bindings below.

```
macro index I  "<search>~T\n"                     "Search for next Tagged"
macro pager I  "<exit><search>~T\n<display-message>" "Jump to next Tagged"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for tagged message by searching (`/`) for `~T`; then you can go to the next one with `n`.
You may also limit (`l`) to tagged messages `~T`.